# Update ProgressDialog on AddValueListener getting data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progressdialog

I launch a ProgressDialog for my app saying "Connecting". So, add the Listener for my Firebase Database and on the method onDataChange I want to change the text of my ProgressDialog for some like "I'm conected, now I'm downloading data". Later loop through the iterable results from Database and hide the ProgressDialog.

My problem is that the ProgressDialog showns but I can't make that update it or change the message. Nothing.

I'm trying with a RunOnUIThread, but nothing works.

Can you help me for reach my goal, or said me for what I can't make this.

```
DialogHandler.showLoadingDialog(InitActivity.this, R.string.connecting,
                            "Connecting", true, false);
                    FDatabaseManager.getInstance().addListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            MyObject obj;
                            InitActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    DialogHandler.updateLoadingDialog(R.string.downloading, "¡Ready! We're downloading data. Please wait.");
                                }
                            });
                            for (DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                obj= i.getValue(MyObject.class);
                                if (SQLiteManager.getInstance(InitActivity.this).existOn(SQLiteContract.TABLE_OBJS, obj.getId())) {
                                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                    values.put(SQLiteContract.ObjColumns.FIELD_LATITUDE, obj.getCoordinates().getLatitude());
                                    values.put(SQLiteContract.ObjColumns.FIELD_LONGITUDE, obj.getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                                    SQLiteManager.getInstance(InitActivity.this).insert(SQLiteContract.TABLE_OBJ, values);
                                }
                            }
                            DialogHandler.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            DialogHandler.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        }
                    }, Constants.DB_OBJS);
```

This is the code for ProgressDialog.

```
public static void showLoadingDialog(final Context context, final int title, final String message, final boolean indeterminate, final boolean cancelable) {
    dismissLoadingDialog();
    loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    loadingDialog.setTitle(title);
    loadingDialog.setMessage(message);
    loadingDialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    loadingDialog.show();
}

public static void updateLoadingDialog(final int title, final String message) {
    if (loadingDialog != null && loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
        loadingDialog.setTitle(title);
        loadingDialog.setMessage(message);
    }
}
```

When I try to make this on anyone method, works fine, but when I try to make on Listener of Firebase Database, not works.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of listening for data isn't quite correct.  The downloading of data starts when you attach the listener.  A connection is established at that time, if one does not already exist.  `onDataChange()` runs when the download is complete.  Note also that `onDataChange()` runs on the Main/UI thread, so there is no need to call `runOnUiThread()`.

The SQLite query and update in your `onDataChange()` method should execute in less than a second, maybe ~200 milliseconds, so showing a dialog during that period is not necessary.